# How to select one value of MySQL JSON array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, database

I am trying to display everything that contains zbs tag2 from a JSON format that is in my MariaDB see screen.

So my query to add the values is owner varhcarm picture TEXT and tags JSON:

```
INSERT INTO json_pics(owner, picture, tags) VALUES ("test", "test.png",'["tag3", "tag4"]');
```

I'm trying to display all entries that have e.g. "tag4" in field tags with a SELECT statement as mentioned above. So that I can filter for one of the things in the brackets. This should work with JSON_CONTAINS or something like that? Image from the example DB: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhqNA.png)

Now id 2 and 3 should be displayed because they both have tag 4 :)

Thanks in advance and many greetings, Flo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to display all entries that have e.g. "tag4" in field tags with a SELECT statement

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM json_pics
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '"tag4"');
```

Comment: Yes thats it. Thank you for the answer! :)